# How to bypass proxy with either VPN or Socks5

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

My university wifi has no restrictions for web sites, however I can not `SSH` or using `remote desktop`. I solved this problem by using `VPN`.

Now at my dormitory I'm behind a proxy with same problem. My question is, is there any way to bypass this proxy by sending all traffics through VPN?
I'm using **Mac** and the `VPN` service is [PrivateInternetAccess](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com) which also support `SOCKS5`

**Edit:**

This is my first time I'm using proxy and I realised that I can use `SSH`. I just didn't configure it correctly.

Comment: well, its hard to proxify ALL traffic unless you are using a virtual network adapter (which is why VPNs do this well and other approaches tend to fail). Lots of apps (especially low level calls like DNS resolution) do not support an application level proxy, so the VPN is definitely the most sure-fire means to achieve your ends. you can look into utilities like Privoxy (or whatever the most recent flavor is), and you can configure many apps to use the socks proxy, but you won't get all of them to call through the proxy.

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas, You right. Now I'm thinking of writing an script for for setting/unsetting proxy on some command line tools (git, npm .etc) this gonna solve this issue, but I'm stuck with other tools which doesn't provide proxy configurations. I tried `Authoxy` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily a simple question to answer because it depends on a lot of variables.

If the proxy is relatively simple, the easiest way round - if you have access to the server outside the network - is to change the port for SSH, a good thing to do anyway since having port 22 exposed on the internet will get you constantly probed by botnets. Port 443 is generally always available through proxies and the proxies generally expect not to be able to decipher the traffic and so will often let SSH traffic through. You can do something similar for remote desktop.

If you can get SSH to work, many other things can be made to work simply by creating suitable tunnels.

On the other hand, more sophisticated network security devices don't just provide a simple proxy, some even go as far as both deep packet inspecting and dynamic risk scoring. Such devices might well detect SSH traffic even on non-standard ports, they might also try to do a man-in-the-middle attack by substituting their own certificates instead of the correct end point cert. This might prevent a simple work around.

If you set up a local SOCKS proxy, you will still need an encrypted tunnel. Either a full VPN solution or a simple SSH based tunnel approach as outlined.

Comment: Thanks @JulianKnight, I don't have enough reputation to vote up so here it is +1 :)

Comment: No worries, you should be able to mark this as the answer tomorrow if you like.

Comment: I think he can accept it as the answer whenever he wants, but he should try to implement what you are saying first and see if it works or if he runs into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution for my problem. I accepted Julian answer because for this general question there would be no better answer.

This is not an answer to my question, but for those of you who are in the same situation I will explain how I work around this problem.

First, for almost all command line tools there would be an option to set your proxy. for example you can config your git like so:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
git config --global https.proxy https://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

And you can unset:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

See this [StackOverflow qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server) you can do the same for `nvm` etc.

For connecting to `mysql` I used `SSH` connection instead of regular way of doing this.

For `Remote Desktop` I found [this tool](http://www.cloudbase.it/freerdp-html5-proxy-windows/) on **Windows** which use `HTML5`for connecting to windows machine. I didn't check this software.